# lambda,map on object arrays in python - Return List of objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to return a list of objects and not list here.
I want to return a list of test objects and not a list of str..

```
class test:
    val = ""
    def __init__(self,v):
        self.val = v
    def tolower(self,k):
        k = k.val.lower()
        return k 

def test_run():
    tests_lst = []
    tests_lst.append(test("TEST-0"))
    tests_lst.append(test("TEST-1"))
    tests_lst.append(test("TEST-2"))
    i_want_object_of_test = map(lambda x:x.val.lower(),tests_lst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

OUTPUT:
['test-0', 'test-1', 'test-2']

i want a list of test objects where each object's val has changed to lower case.

Comment: Your question is so unclear. Please state clearly what output is expected and what output you are getting. Your current code is not outputting or printing anything...

Comment: I want map(lambda x:x.val.lower(),tests_lst) to return a list of test objects. It returns a list of string instead.

Comment: Firstly, when you write`val = ""` in your class body, that is a *class-level* variable, not an instance attribute. Are you coming from a language like Java, by any chance? Later in `__init__`, when you write `self.val = v` you create an instance variable which shadows the class variable. Anyway, `val.lower()` returns a string which populates the list being returned by the map. Maps are functional constructs, meant for transforming data, and you should not use them to alter state (although you can if you really want to). Instead, make a for-loop, `for x in test_list: x.val = x.val.lower()`

Comment: I don't want to use a for loop, I'm trying to see if there is a slick way to do it using lambdas, map or may be list comprehension..

Comment: @digicoder Don't do that. That is not "slick." It will make your code less readable and affords no advantages. People don't expect state-changes in functional constructs. If you really must (which you really don't), make a method which alters the state then returns the object i.e. something like `self.val = self.val.lower()` and then `return self` and then use that method in your `lambda`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : That's precisely why the method tolower() is written, so that i can do map(lambda x: x.tolower(),tests_lst), But it returns a list of str and not a list of test objects.. I want a list of test objects from this operation.

Comment: @digicoder What is the `k` parameter for? As it is written, it is expecting a Test object. Anyway, the method would have to `return self` if you want to populate a list using map or a comprehension. I have literally written the two lines of code necessary for the body of your function in my previous comment.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : I totally get your point, for curiosity's sake, can you tell me whether you can return a list of objects versus a list of str using list comprehension, map and lambda. I'm studying the python compiler let's say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear. I'll answer by what I understand.

What I understand is that you are trying to create a new list of test objects, with the values as lower case.

You can do this either by changing the state of each of the objects in a for loop (changing state is usually not recommended):

```
for test_obj in test_lst:
    test_obj.val = test_obj.val.lower()
```

A way to do it through a list comprehension is to create new test instances:

```
i_want_object_of_test = [test(test_obj.val.lower()) for test_obj in test_lst]
```

Besides, there are a few problems with your test class:

- It is an old style class, you should always inherit from object in your classes: `class test(object):`
- You define a class variable by putting `val = ""'` in your class defenition, you then override it in each instance.
- Your tolower method gets another test instance (k) and returns its value as lower case. I assume you want to either return a new test object or change the current one in place. Either way the method should only use `self`.

Comment: [test(test_obj.val.lower()) for test_obj in test_lst] is the magic line i was looking for, I'm aware of not making the object state change while iterating. Thanks for your help on the python guidelines as well.

Comment: What if i had car(object): and in that i had engine which is an instance of Engine(object): and engine had a text property called val="", I wanted to change all val property to lower case. Can you please Help.

Comment: @digicoder Depends on whether you want to change the state of every engine's val, change every car's engine, or create copies of them altogether.

Comment: @digicoder Changing state is probably best done in a for loop, while creating copies of the objects should be done in the same manner with slight changes: have a function `from copy import deepcopy; def copy_with_new_val(car): copied = deepcopy(car); copied.engine.val = copied.engine.val.lower(); return copied` then have your changes like this: `changed_cars = map(copy_with_new_val, cars)`